# Как сделать плавный якорь , если меню сделана через wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Как собственное такое реализовать? плагином или скриптом?

Comment: Что ты имеешь в виду под термином «плавный якорь»? Что бы страница плавно скроллилась к якорю?

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz Да, чтобы плавно скроллилась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужно что-то вроде этого. Пример на jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  // Ищем сслки с якорями
  $('[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {
    // Блокируем станадртное поведение ссылки
    event.preventDefault();
    // И устанавливаем хэш в адресной строке руками
    window.location.hash = anchor;
    
    // Берём id из якоря
    var anchor = $(this).attr('href');
    // Если нет элемента с этим id, уходим
    if(!$(anchor).length)
      return;
    
    // Получаем координату нужного элемента
    var scrollPoint = $(anchor).offset().top;
    // Идём к этому элементу, со скоростью в 500 мс
    $(document.body).animate({scrollTop: scrollPoint}, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Стили только для того, что бы увеличить страницу в примере */
#sample-wrap > a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sample-wrap">
  <a href="#anchor">Ссылка на якорь</a>
  <div id="anchor">Элемент с якорем</div>
  <a href="#sample-wrap">Вернуться наверх</a>
</div>
```